# Pearson Correlations between time and value in a time series

Tags: time-series, pearson-r

I have two series here mothly data:

`var1 = {'Month': 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}`
`var2 = {'Rain': 10,20,5,70,21,65,1,24,56,68}`

Is it possible to calculate pearson correlations between the two? and use that as `m` for filtering outliers  e.g `Mean(Rain) +- m x standard_dev(Rain)` .
Im new to stats and doing a forecasting problem where I dont want to detect outliers but model them. Please help

Comment: Welcome to this site! Why do you need the correlation coefficient if you are only interested in filtering data based on mean and SD?

Comment: woudn't that help in filtering, as a slope ``m`` instead of having to twick ''m'' when filtering, like 1,2 or 3 std dev from mean?

Comment: Sure, I didn't notice the `m` in your equation! However, detrending is usually done using regression. Next, there's detection of outliers in time-series analysis, and I would suggest you look for best practices in related threads on this site.